# How can I specify which items will appear on this page through a link on another page

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors, bootstrap-5

page 1 :
When you click on one of these links, it should take you to the second page, and only the item for this part will appear

```
<ul class="portfolio-filters list-inline">
    <li ><a href="page2.html/#webdesign-filter">Web Design</a></li>
    <li ><a href="page2.html/#responsive-filter">Responsive</a></li>
    <li ><a href="page2.html/#wordpress-filter">Wordpress</a></li>
 </ul>
```

page 2:

```
<div>
     <div class="" id="webdesign-filter">
      <h4>Web Design</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="" id="responsive-filter">
      <h4>Responsive</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>

    <div class=""  id="wordpress-filter">
      <h4>Wordpress</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The hash portion of URLs won't work the way you're intending. If you want only that content to be present, create separate pages for each

Comment: I was going to do that, but I wanted to reduce the file size because there are some repeated or common elements in these three pages, and can the number of these pages increase over time, and this will cause some problems

Comment: Repeating content is a great use-case for a framework such as https://kit.svelte.dev/ where you can use templates with the repeating code, and load each page inside the template. The framework will automatically either send full HTML or download only new content on redirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div>
<div class="hidden" id="webdesign-filter">
    <h4>Web Design</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>

<div class="hidden" id="responsive-filter">
    <h4>Responsive</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>

<div class="hidden"  id="wordpress-filter">
    <h4>Wordpress</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
</div>


<style>
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
</style>

<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const { hash } = document.location
    if (hash) {
        if (document.querySelector(hash)) {
            document.querySelector(hash).style.display = "block"
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Very creative solution. Keep in mind the HTML is still loaded to the client, and if the user disables JavaScript the section will not become visible.

Comment: Thank you, this method worked for me, but can I change the content of the link to improve it?